# Importance of Time Features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering, supervised-learning

if you have a time series and you want to do some predictions, what **time feature** should you use ?

lets say we are trying to predict *how many people visit a certain website*, we have data for the visits for the last 2 years, what should we include as a time feature ?
and if we use more features might it make our model less accurate ?

**the features i can think of are the following:**

```
Date index(1-700)
Week number (1-53)
Day of the week (1-7)
Month(1-12)
Day of the month(1-31)
Day of the year(1-365)
Year
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Week number (1-53)` and `Day of the year(1-365)` in the same model, you will have collinearity. You can derive the week number from the day of the year, so the former doesn't add any additional information.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813884/correlated-features-and-classification-accuracy) explains it in more detail.

Comment: Yes however, i don't have SO many features and have way more samples then features, so this shouldn't be a cause that decrease the accuracy of my model. 
As for the Date index is it so important to use it ?

Comment: Are you trying to predict the number of visits in a given day? Which algorithm are you using for prediction? Date Index `(t)` relates an observation taken at `t` to `t-1` or `t+1`, etc. It is your temporal reference point. I guess its importance would rely on the model you wish to use.

Comment: exactly number of visits in a given day, i try to predict the next 10 days, sometimes more or less

Comment: "_...i try to predict the **next** 10 days_", so you would need the date index.